# Error in setup.php when running wordpress on linux using app-engine php sdk

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I am facing few errors trying to run WordPress on php app-engine on Ubuntu.

1. The [instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress) mention using `dev_appserver.py -R`, but `-R` is an invalid argument?
2. The server starts well (I was able to run helloworld successfully) but on visiting, I get the following error:

   ```
   ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.15
   Content-type: text/html

   <br />
   <b>Warning</b>:  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in         <b>/home/ubuntu/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
   <br />
   <b>Warning</b>:  require(wordpress/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in     <b>/home/ubuntu/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
   <br />
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  require(): Failed opening required 'wordpress/index.php' (include_path='/home/ubuntu/wordpress:/home/ubuntu/google_appengine/php/sdk') in     <b>/home/ubuntu/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
   ```

Looking further into this in google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php/setup.php line 11, `$actualPath = stream_resolve_include_path($relativePath);` , the `$relativePath` is `wordpress` and the `$actualPath` received is an empty string which seems to be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure were the "-R" flag came from. I can't find it being documented.

Have you made sure the application folder is called "wordpress" and there is an index.php file in there?

also make sure your directory structure looks like the following:

```
    .
    ├── app.yaml
    ├── cron.yaml
    ├── main.php
    ├── php.ini
    └── wordpress
        ├── index.php
        ├── license.txt
        ├── readme.html
        ├── wp-activate.php
        ├── wp-admin
        ├── wp-blog-header.php
        ├── wp-comments-post.php
        ├── wp-config.php
        ├── wp-config-sample.php
        ├── wp-content
        ├── wp-cron.php
        ├── wp-includes
        ├── wp-links-opml.php
        ├── wp-load.php
        ├── wp-login.php
        ├── wp-mail.php
        ├── wp-settings.php
        ├── wp-signup.php
        ├── wp-trackback.php
        └── xmlrpc.php

    4 directories, 21 files
```

I just tested the installation instructions and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I figured out that wordpress folder needed to be in the application wordpress folder. And that works great. I was dumping all the wordpress files in the application root.